# NSUInteger incompatible with NSUInteger?

Tags: ios, implicit-conversion, nsuinteger

`index` is a `NSUInteger` on both my parent and child view controller. But when I try to pass the `NSUInteger` value for `index` I get a warning on this line: `controller.index = index;` saying "incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSUInteger from NSUInteger" and tells me to fix-it with `&(index)`. But when I convert it to `&(index)` I no longer get a number value from `index`. What am I doing wrong? (new to programming) thanks!

```
- (PhotoViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{
    self.image = [self photoAtIndex:index];

    if (self.image == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    PhotoViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoViewController"];

    controller.image = self.image;
    controller.index = index;

    return controller;
}
```

Comment: There missing a pointer somewhere...

Comment: (moral: you want to read the **exact** error message, and you want to **pay attention** while reading.)

Comment: "..incompatible *integer* to *pointer* conversion.."

Comment: Search on the error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=incompatible+integer+to+pointer+conversion+assigning

Comment: okay, makes more sense now. I was unaware of the correct way to declare integers. (self taught noob still in my infancy)

Comment: [C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628) by Brian W. Kernighan , Dennis M. Ritchie. Gotta learn the underlying language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably declared your `index` property in your `PhotoViewController` class as `NSUInteger *index` instead of just `NSUInteger index`. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: It's probably worth explaining that - despite its name - `NSInteger` is a native type.